# Windows support for headphones pilot

Tags: windows, iphone, remote, headphones

I have [Harman Kardon CL headphones](http://www.harmankardon.com/estore/hk/us/products/CL/HARKAR-CL_HK_US) with remote made for iPhone. Is there any way I could use this remote in Windows (increase/decrease volume etc.) ?

Comment: Have you tried it? The manual says it has an "Apple-compatible" remote. I don't see where it states it is exclusively for Apple. Give it a try. Some features you'd expect from using with your iPhone may not work with a standard headphone jack on a PC.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: Not likely it would. The special circuits in the iPhone which allow the remote to work are simply not available on the standard headphone jack of a PC. I believe the headphones would have to have a USB interface to work with a PC. I must admit, it would be a nice feature to be able to use with your PC.